# Inline vs included js and css?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, http

In an environment with at least 500ms latency over 2G mobile connections (~0.1mbps), what's the fastest and most efficient way of sending a about 10kb of css and js, in around 5-10 files on the server, to the client?

I can think of three options:

1. combining all js to one file and all css to one file
2. linking all css and js files one by one
3. inline everything

I know google uses inline, but that's probably just to save server sockets. They are even saving ram by running in stateless mode - they trust the clients to remember the sessions for them. Server power isn't an issue at all.

On the other hand, facebook seem to autogenerate their css (their names are base64 encoded), but into over 10 different files sent to the user, and they don't even seem to optimize it that heavily; only some whitespace removal.

I'm already passing all the files through a function that compresses everything, so any one of these are feasible. I don't want to choose the first alternative because it's easier.

The first two takes advantage of caching (the second one a bit less than the first one) but the second only requires three requests to the server, and the third only requires one get request from the server (ignoring the few images we might have on some of the pages).

Does Android / iOS cache js and css across restarts of the browser? If not, then inline sounds better.

The only goal is to minimize the average load time of the user. Each user will be spending about 100 page loads on the site per day, seeing about 40 css and js files per day. The css and js is basically static content. It's set to cache 30 days, and we change the url if the file changes using `/path/to/file.ext?md5-hash-of-file`. Also, everything is gzipped wherever possible.

EDIT:

I think i should clarify the two options I found for number two. Is it a good idea to use a single file for css and js across the whole site? It would only use two requests and remove any double (or septuple) caching because a single function is in two or more different combined js files, but a download of up to 1MB doesn't sound that good.

Today it's basically one combined css per view, so every time you view the same page again the content is cached. However, some js and css is used on more than one page.

Comment: 1 means less requests are sent, but as you're setting cache headers it shouldn't matter much. As for 3, is your page dynamically generated? If so it won't be cached and inlining CSS/JS would a terrible idea. As for Android/iOS caching files or not, that will depend on the size of those files.

Comment: if you use ajax navigation, inline is easier and doesn't always require wasting bandwidth: ex; swap out the body, leaving inline js/css in head. if you refresh the page often, a couple well-cached external urls generally perform the best. keep in mind that two 50kb files on 2g will typically transfer faster than 1 100kb file owing to pipe-lining. if you have a lot of lag however, it may be faster to lookup/xfer one url than two.

Comment: all pages are dynamically generated, php, so caching wouldn't work at all then. Do you have any idea of what file sizes are cached?

Comment: ios used to top off at 25kb/url, but that was back in ios4. i think it's basically unlimited in io6, allowing 10mb/max per page. also, you can still cache generated pages, just use an expires header and your existing version system.

Comment: Inline Javascript is a bad idea, because of parsing issues. Tricks like putting the source between `<!--` `-->` all have drawbacks. (In this case the fact that `-->` is a possible valid sequence in Javascript itself.) Javascript in files of their own don't have these problems!

Comment: The fastest and most efficient way will be to send everything in one go. The first load experience might not be great, but when you say *‹‹The only goal is to minimize the average load time of the user››* you have already decided that it does not matter here.

Comment: @HenrikHelmers how can I be sure all browsers actually cache the resources, and that their cache isn't reset before their next visit? The users will visit the site at least every 4 days.

Comment: You cannot make sure, that is up to each user agent. You can follow some best practices (https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching), but in the end it is up to the browser how and what to cache. Some (slightly dated) tests reveal that they differ quite a lot (http://www.guypo.com/uncategorized/mobile-browser-cache-sizes-round-2/). Perhaps you should consider looking into HTML5 Appcache (http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#applicationcache) for more control.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the usage. For a page with only **one time visitors** , I would recommend inlining everything. This makes for a faster initial load (a single request vs multiple requests) and easier to work with. This is the case for landing pages, help pages, wizards and similar one-use pages.

However, if you are expecting **recurring visitors**, I'd recommend using an external file. While the first load will be slower, you make it up with near-zero load time afterwards for these assets. This is the case for most websites.

Answer (score 1):

> inline css and javascript will make your page so heavy.its a very good
>   practice to merge your all style sheets and all javascript files into
>   one and include them into your page.this will make your page very fast
>   as compared to inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with #2, linking to each file, is that the biggest factor in load time for small elements is round trip time, not file size. It takes several round trips to set up the connection to get each file. This also means that you should combine your css and js files. In your high-latency environment, round trips will be especially painful. [Here's google's advice on round trips](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt)

As others have pointed out, #3, inlining, means that files cannot be cached. It can slow down load times because of the increased size of the html. However you avoid the roundtrip penalty.

In your environment, I would also recommend [looking at the HTML5 application cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/whats-offline/#toc-application-cache) to optimize caching for css and js files. You would need to convert your app to use AJAX calls instead of loading html pages, but doing that also reduces the needed data transfer.